# What is the function of this tool of my scissors?

Tags: equipment

What is the function of this part of my scizors.
[image]

Answer (score 24):

This feature is described as a bottle/jar opener on a product page for shears that look like yours from the photo:

[image]

- Source: [Royal Norfolk via DollarTree](https://www.dollartree.com/royal-norfolk-cutlery-kitchen-shears-85-in/121235): "Also, has bottle/jar opener inset on the handle for added convenience."

Looking at other available scissors with this type of feature, the manufacturers describe it in various ways:

- [Williams-Sonoma](https://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/williams-sonoma-open-kitchen-kitchen-shears/): "Handle has a built-in bottle opener"
- [Victorinox](https://www.victorinox.com/us/en/Products/Cutlery/Scissors/Multipurpose-Kitchen-Shears/p/7.6363.3): "The Shears feature a cavity designed to crack nuts or to help twist open stubborn jar lids"
- [OXO](https://www.homedepot.com/p/OXO-Good-Grips-Stainless-Steel-Kitchen-and-Herb-Scissors-1072121/302032710): "Built-in herb stripper removes fresh herbs from tough stems" (this looks different from your picture, but I wonder if it would still work)

Image gallery of all products with description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzZVO.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure why they say "jar" - those jaws are far too small for anything but the tiniest jars.

Comment: @ChrisH yeah, I tried to find videos of people actually using the "jar opener" feature but couldn't find anything useful after a quick search

Comment: My guess is that it is used in jars to make a small opening for air to come through the lid. I always do it with tomato jars but prefer using a specific bottle opener @ChrisH

Comment: @M.K I can't imagine it doing that as well as a teaspoon handle or butter knife.  One pair I have (or had)  with these jaws also had a bottle opener in the back of one of the blades.  Maybe I'll look for them in my camping cooking stuff tonight

Comment: You have to realize that at one time, a reputable company decided to make scissors with this feature for a certain purpose (probably a nut cracker), but then _everyone_ has copied it and possibly mistranslated the purpose along the way.  There is no way this would work as a "jar opener" and would probably just bend up the lid on a bottle and not work well.

Comment: [This page](https://www.cnet.com/home/kitchen-and-household/how-to-use-kitchen-shears/) shows how you'd use it to open jars. I will say, I have these scissors and trying to open a stubborn jar like this seems pretty unsafe.

Comment: Works great for opening tight soda bottle caps. Source: I do that.

Answer (score 16):

I only know this part as a bottle opener.
I would not try to open nuts with it, if the nut is hard, the scissor could be ruined.

Comment: Yep. I have broken a pair of scissors exactly the same as OP's. The handle parts end up breaking due to the force to open nuts! but opening bottles is fine

Comment: There are kitchen shears that will not break if you use them to crack nuts, and maybe ones that are less durable have the same "features" even if they can’t handle the forces.

Comment: Hmmm. What type of bottle is this supposed to open?

Comment: @EricDuminil: A jar with a screw top.  The teeth dig into the metal, giving you a handle to push on, instead of just smooth round metal.  Other ways to open a tough jar might involve a grippy material like rubberized that won't leave teeth marks on the metal, but the idea is to amplify the squeezing force of a hand to get a better grip on the metal that won't slip as easily when you try to turn.

Comment: I also find this useful for loosening and tightening the nut (the hardware, not the food) that secures the handle on my pepper grinder.

Comment: @Fattie Every nutcracker I've ever seen that wasn't the kind that looks like a solider has teeth. The teeth grip the nut and prevent it from shooting out of the nutcracker when you squeeze it. The teeth also increase the pressure by decreasing the contact area to crack and penetrate the nut's shell with less force. Regardless of the purpose for this part of the shears, having teeth actually supports the idea that it's a nutcracker, it doesn't contradict it.

Answer (score 14):

At least according to [the KitchenSeer blog](https://kitchenseer.com/what-is-middle-part-of-kitchen-scissors-for/) the middle part of the shears is for cracking nuts (although it can also be used as a bottle or jar opener).

Comparing to a dedicated nutcracker pictured as below, the similarity is notable.

[image: image of a nutcracker]

Comment: Yep, definitely supposed to be a nutcracker, though actually using it as one is generally a bad idea, as most scissors do not have a hinge that’s anywhere near as robust as the one you will find on a good dedicated nutcracker.

Comment: It's OK for hazelnuts (@AustinHemmelgarn) but not walnuts - not strong enough and too small.  That said I've been using a hammer even for hazelnuts after unexpectedly finding a good wild source. I did have a pair of scissors identical to those in the picture.  They broke somehow, but not cracking nuts

Comment: It's definitely not.  It's just for opening bottle tops or similar things that need to be grabbed.  You could never in a million years crack nuts with it!

Comment: @ChrisH I broke one like that while cracking nuts. They were decent scissors before that but not top tier quality. Why the designers thought it'd be a good idea to crack nuts with that is beyond me

Comment: @Hobbamok I don't normally need nutcrackers but I went back to the toolbox last night for pliers which work very well.  I think I've got a pair of scissor like that in the van.  Maybe I'll try them against hazelnuts later

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Walnuts aren't even particularly hard to crack other than their size.  Of commercially available ones Brazil nuts I find much harder to crack.  They're still easy compared to the hickory nuts from my parents tree.  Trying to use a handheld lever cracker like that was a frequently failed grip strength test, a framing or baby sledge hammer worked much better.

Comment: *" You could never in a million years crack nuts with it! "* @Fattie It's possible to crack nuts with bare hands, so surely adding the scissors inbetween the hand and the nut shouldn't make it impossible.

Comment: (Macadamia nuts are the absolute hardest to crack. Basically, only a vise works.) Kitchen shears can probably be used to crack walnuts, but I wouldn't suggest them for hazelnuts or anything harder.